# SolidWorks Edrawing viewer in Java

Tags: java, solidworks

Is there a library to load edrawings into a JFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to limit the input files to DXF files, perhaps this will do? http://www.escape.de/~quincunx/dxfviewer/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts:

- eDrawings is based on HOOPS3D file format. It contains a compressed xml hoops stream (open an eDrawings file in your favorite hex editor and you'll find a typical zip PK signature around offset 0x5C)

  libraries are available to view HOOPS3D files in java: [HoopsJava](http://docs.techsoft3d.com/visualize/HoopsJava/ProgrammingGuide_C.html) (however I don't know about licensing constraints of it).

So a path may be to extract the XML stream and load it in HoopsJava.